# Error in nobs.default(x) : no 'nobs' method is available with MuMIn::model.sel()

Tags: r, mixed-models, gam, mumin

I am trying to select top models from a list of model outputs. The models were run using uGamm(), the wrapper function that is supposed to allow gamm4 models to be used with the MuMIn model selection and averaging functions.

Example model:

```
fit <- 
    uGamm(y~ s(x1) + s(x2, bs = 'cc') + s(x3) +  s(X,Y, bs= 'ts') + s(r1, bs = 're') +s (r2, bs = 're') + s(r3, bs = 're'),
          data = dat,
          lme4 = TRUE)
```

There are 3 random effects (r1, r2, and r3).
I tried to load in the model outputs, and each output consists of a mer object and a gam object. I wanted to run the model selection on the gam objects.

```
gamm_list <- list()

for (i in 1:length(mod_names){
  mod <- readRDS(mod_names[[i]])
  #keeping only the gam object, otherwise the objects are too large to load into env
  gamm_list[[i]] <- mod$gam
}

model.sel <- model.sel(gamm_list)
```

But I keep generating "Error in nobs.default(x) : no'nobs' method is available".
This error does not occur if I do the same code above using the mod$mer object instead of mod$gam. The ultimate goal is to identify the top models to generate predictions with predict().

Comment: I tried setting `nobs.gam <- stats:::nobs.glm` but that only got me a little bit farther.

Comment: @BenBolker, it seems that packages such as MuMIn and AICcmodavg don't really cooperate with gamm4 or gam objects to do these model averaging/model selection tasks. If I do the AIC calculations manually and try to calculate the weights to select models, would it be acceptable to then use the mer objects instead? Attempting to calculate AIC on the gam objects results in errors as well (functions are not defined for gams).

Comment: Where is `uGamm()` from? If that is a typical formula, you're not using the efficiency of specifying random effects in gamm4 - those should be in the `random` argument not via the spline-as-ranef basis `bs = "re"`.

Comment: I don't understand why `AIC()` on a **gam** object would fail - there is a method for that. If you are applying it to the `$gam` component that might return a length 0 numeric but that's because these really aren't proper "gam" objects. You could just apply the AIC function to the `mer` component.

Comment: @GavinSimpson `uGamm()` is the wrapper function for the MuMIn package, theoretically so that the MuMIn package can perform model selection on gamm objects from packages like gamm4. The random effects are specified in that way so that I can exclude them later on in the predict() call (i.e., `exclude = 's(random_effect)'`). I was unable to exclude random effects during predictions if they were specified in the `random` argument.

Comment: @megsruppUNBC Then I don't understand why you need to use `gamm4` - can't you use `gam()` here? Does that work without the nobs issue? If you're not using the `random` argument to `gamm4()` there is no reason to use that function, just use `gam()` which *does* work with `update()` so won't need `Ugamm()` either.

Comment: To be honest, I've never fully understood how the `$mer` and `$gam` components encapsulate different parts of the model ...